Metaflow Client Get Run Status
I am using metaflow client API in Python to get the status of a specific Run. But the finished attribute in the run object is always False, even I can see the run failed in Metaflow UI hours ago. According the Metaflow doc I believe the run.finished should be False and run.successful should also be False if the run failed
My question is how to use the metaflow client properly to get the status of a metaflow run?
This is my code
   from metaflow import Flow

   flow_name = "MyFlow"
   flow = Flow(flow_name)
   run = flow[metaflow_run_id]
   if run.finished:
        # some check here

